# Add scrollbar to java swing textarea

Tags: java, swing

I have this java code:

```
private JTextArea textArea;
private JButton returnButton;


private ButtonListener buttonListener;

public LessonView() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(580, 300));

    buttonListener = new ButtonListener();

    returnButton = new JButton("Inapoi");
    returnButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    buttonPanel.add(returnButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

I want to add a scrollbar to this textarea. How can I do this?
My text is very long and I need a scrollbar.
Thank you!

Comment: Change `textArea = new JTextArea(); .. textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(580, 300));` to something like `textArea = new JTextArea(5,20);`. Specifying the number of rows and columns will better suggest a size.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decorate your JTextArea with a JScrollPane :

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

and then, replace

```
add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

by

```
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```